# in the textit{}, I have error with the statement telling me to use $ $

Tags: bibliographies, urls

```
\bibitem{Shiva2014}
Shiva.A, Sethi.M.(2014).Understanding Dynamic Relationship among Gold Price, Exchange Rate and Stock Markets.\textit{gbr.sagepub.com/content/16/5_suppl/93S.refs}.
```

I don't want any math form, but latex tell me to use $ $ in the `\textit{gbr.sagepub.com/content/16/5_suppl/93S.refs}` because of subscript at `5_suppl` and I don't want to use math form. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome! Please post a complete example rather than a mere fragment of code. And this has nothing to do with either Biblatex or LaTeX 3. You cannot typeset a URL without doing something extra if it includes characters which LaTeX or TeX treats specially. Here, the `_` is certainly going to be problematic. The `url` package might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an underscore that you want, just type

```
\textit{gbr.sagepub.com/content/16/5\_suppl/93S.refs}
```

But it is better to use the `url` package, which allows line breaks in urls at correct points:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlFont{\itshape\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\textit{gbr.sagepub.com/content/16/5\_suppl/93S.refs} \medskip

 \url{gbr.sagepub.com/content/16/5_suppl/93S.refs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better to use the `url` package, as it allows line breaks in a coherent way.